# Web audio API getFloatTimeDomainData sometimes works, sometimes it doesn't [HEISENBUG]

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, web-audio-api

With an ionic angular app, I am trying to get the audio signal from navigator.getMediaDevices({ audio : true} ) to then use an audio analyser to get the float time domain data.

The code executes as follows:

somewhere in the service constructor:

```
this.audioContext = new window.AudioContext();
this.analyser = this.audioContext.createAnalyser();
this.analyser.fftSize = this.settings.values.fftSize; // Valued 8192
this.audioBuffer = new Float32Array(this.analyser.fftSize);
```

Then, somewhere else I toggle the stream with getUserMedia

```
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
    .then((stream => {
      //console.log('Mic stream OK! ', stream);
      this.stream = stream;
      this.isCapturing = true;
      // Create an AudioNode from the stream
      this.mediaStreamSource = this.audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(this.stream);
      this.mediaStreamSource.connect(this.analyser);

      //start the analysis cycle. This is non related but it starts the cycle that uses the getfloatTimeDomainData(buffer)
      this.animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(this.streamAnalysis.bind(this));
    }).bind(this))
    .catch(err => console.log('[PMATIC] Error accessing mic: ', err));
```

this prompts my users to enable the app to listen from the microphone
[image]
[image]

And then, in the analysis cycle (The cycle is constantly recording until the user prompts it to stop)

private tuneAnalysis():void {
this.analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData(this.audioBuffer);

However, whenever I access this.audioBuffer, the array elements are  always equal to 0.
[image]
Sometimes it works, but 99% of the times it doesn't. This used to work and works fine when I deploy in a mobile android app using cordova, however, here, in google chrome it simply doesn't ,or at least not reliably. And I can't seem to find a pattern of why it works or it doesn't work. I've checked my microphone and in use with other apps it works correctly. No exception is raised, i can record from my mic perfectly with other apps, and I also ensure other apps that may be using the microphone are closed when I try to record. I'm using typescript and i've tried declaring the variables both public and private but it doesn't really work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898307/zero-value-data-in-createmediastreamsource-input-buffer-when-recording-using-web)

Comment: Nope, not at all, but I just realized the problem lies here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55026293/google-chrome-javascript-issue-in-getting-user-audio-the-audiocontext-was-not

Apparently this has been newly enforced in a new chrome update. so that's why it stopped working. THANK YOU GOOGLE for doing this. I love spending hours trying to figure out why things stopped working out of no where.